# UIScrollView not scrolling with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm really stuck trying to figure it out why UIScrollView won't scroll. I will post screenshot of my application:

[image]

And structure for this controller is following:

[image]

I have two horizontal collection views and one vertical collection view. The problem is that when i try to scroll vertical collection view, uiscrollview is not working.

I'm pretty new to the Swift and iOS programming, so please let me know if I need to provide more informations.

Note: I have heard that this is bad idea for implementation (UICollectionView inside UIScrollView), but I'm coming from Android Development and there this was a good practice.

Comment: Would you mind adding your code?

Comment: _Note: I have heard that this is bad idea for implementation (UICollectionView inside UIScrollView), but I'm coming from Android Development and there this was a good practice._ I just asked my colleague. He said this is not true. He is an android developer.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Yes, it is good practice. You have special NestedScrollView which is used in this kind of situations.

Comment: Ah... yes. He just confirmed that is true. My bad. Sorry.

Comment: why do you need the _scroll-view_ at the first place?

Comment: @holex I need it for scrolling through whole content.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic, use one collection-view with custom layout and cells then.

Comment: @holex thank you for you answer. I know that I should probably do like that, but I have already written all code and done design in storyboard, so if it is possible to do it with scrollview It would be much easier for me and faster.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to increase ContentHeight of UIScrollView as per height of UICollectionView